# Why is my faucet wallet on Alphanet not recognized?

Tags: wallets, alphanet

I'm running Ubuntu 18.03 LTS on a machine with Intel inside Core i5, and with Docker and Docker Compose I have successfully set-up a running node on Alphanet. I downloaded a faucet wallet, however this is not recognized. What am I doing wrong? It could be something very simple, due to the fact that I'm not an experienced programmer. With this wallet I would like to test the functionality of VIAZ. Thanks for helping me out.

These are the steps that I tried:

```
easy@easy-VPCEJ2M1E:~$ ./alphanet.sh 

restart Stopping alphanet_endorser-003-PsddFKi3_1 ... 
done ... 
The script is up to date. ... 
Creating alphanet_endorser-003-PsddFKi3_1 ... 
done 

easy@easy-VPCEJ2M1E:~$ ./alphanet.sh client activate account alice with "container:'/home/easy/Downloads/tz1YpvKafoN8vw8fAR12ijey9MX3LHLqGydA.json'" 

alphanet: Pulling from tezos/tezos Digest: sha256:9e0530c93507c6d59422278facfa138ef5e282813db5ee045413e9e9026696e9 
Status: Image is up to date for tezos/tezos:alphanet 
lstat /home/easy/': no such file or directory –
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you did, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: Dear Tom, this is the input and output.       easy@easy-VPCEJ2M1E:~$ ./alphanet.sh restart
Stopping alphanet_endorser-003-PsddFKi3_1 ... done
...
The script is up to date.
...
Creating alphanet_endorser-003-PsddFKi3_1 ... done
easy@easy-VPCEJ2M1E:~$ ./alphanet.sh client activate account alice with "container:'/home/easy/Downloads/tz1YpvKafoN8vw8fAR12ijey9MX3LHLqGydA.json'"
alphanet: Pulling from tezos/tezos
Digest: sha256:9e0530c93507c6d59422278facfa138ef5e282813db5ee045413e9e9026696e9
Status: Image is up to date for tezos/tezos:alphanet
lstat /home/easy/': no such file or directory

Comment: Hope you understand this.

Comment: If you are just wanting to test the VIAZ demo, it may be easier to use the faucet account with light wallet like TezBox - here's a guide: https://github.com/viazofficial/web-app/blob/master/ALPHA_DEMO.md (you don't need to run a full node to use the viaz demo)

Comment: I had a similar problem - node on alphanet was working, but could not make any operations with faucet.  Running node was not enough. In my case the node wasn't completely bootstrapped yet, this is why. You can start by checking if your node was bootstrapped completely - run this:   ./tezos-client bootstrapped

Answer (score 1):

I would try leaving out the single quotes from that `container:` parameter. I suspect that the extra level of quoting is causing problems.  That is, try:

```
 ./alphanet.sh client activate account alice with "container:/home/easy/Downloads/tz1YpvKafoN8vw8fAR12ijey9MX3LHLqGydA.json"
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to update your node. `003-PsddFKi3…` is the old protocol, should be `004-Pt24m4xiP…` by now.